# I have a rails 4 app with an iframe that doesn't load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

As stated, I have a rails 4 app that has a couple iframes from other sites. I have been able to get 1 of them to load when the page loads and can be found [here](http://myshirtfund.com/sell_now). The page I cannot get to load is [here](http://www.myshirtfund.com/buy_now). It will load if you refresh the page.

The code for the one that works is as follows, I have tried the same for the page that doesn't load without any luck.

```
after_action :allow_cognito_iframe    
def allow_cognito_iframe
         response.headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'ALLOW-FROM https://services.cognitoforms.com'
     end
```

Comment: both of the iframes works on my machine, second one takes a little bit long time, I thought it won't work but end of the day it worked.

Comment: thats cool, I wonder why they don't pull up on my machine, until I refresh. This happens on multiple browsers